# How do I set JFrame size from different class

Tags: java, swing, class, jframe

I've got two classes. My QuizatMainClass class and a class called window. I'm trying to create a window from the Quizat class with a set size but it won't compile. I've set the parameter to (x and y) e.g (1080 and 720). But it does'nt like that. I'm new to Java and don't really understand why I can't do this. The way the IDE fixes it is with something about superclass stuff. If someone could explain what this means to me or a more simple way to do what I'm trying to run I'd appreciate it. Layman's terms please.

QuizatMainClass:

```
package Quizat;

public class QuizatMainClass extends Window{

    public static void main(String[] args) {

    Window QuizatHomeScreen = new Window(1080, 20);

    }

}
```

Window Class:

```
package Quizat;

import javax.swing.JFrame;

public class Window{

    public Window(int x, int y){
        JFrame window = new JFrame();
        window.setSize(x,y);
        window.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
        window.setResizable(false);
        window.setVisible(true);
    }

}
```

Comment: If code won't compile, please post the compiler's error message with your question (not in comments).

Comment: Please see edit to answer for more detail.

Comment: `new Window(1080, 20);` What programmers usually intend when doing things like this is to make a content pane of that size, which setting the window that size won't achieve because it does not account for the frame decorations..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The explanation for your problem is that since QuizatMainClass extends the Window class, and Window has a specific parameter-using constructor, the QuizatMainClass will either need to create a constructor that specifically calls Window's super constructor with parameters, or else give Window a default no-arg constructor.

Having said that your real problem is that you're misusing inheritance. QuizatMainClass shouldn't extend the Window class, that's it.

Comment: Thanks a lot you're right that worked. Why did that cause an issue though?

Comment: @Cutter: when you give a class a non-default constructor, one with parameters, it loses its default parameterless constructor. If you inherit from this class, your new child class must call the specific super constructor within its own constructor, passing in the appropriate parameters. The other option again is to give the parent class a no-args constructor.